# scapy won't install on dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I am trying to run a python code on a docker container that is using scapy. But for some reason when I am trying to install the package on my `Dockerfile` the command that supposed to install the package is running forever. This is how its look when running the command `docker build -t image .`:
[Image from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBxEA.png)

**Can someone please help me fix this**
**My Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ADD server.py .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install python3
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN apt-get -y install python3-scapy
```

Comment: 1) Please don't post errors as images. 2) The error shows that it's clearly waiting for input from you. Maybe scapy has a non-interactive install option?

Comment: How can I find that installation type? I really dont have that much experience in this type of thing, I would really appreciate if you can help me with that.

Comment: Why does errors can not be posted as images?

Comment: Can I just add that input to the command insted of looking for a non-interactive insttalation?

Answer (score 1):

I successfully fix that issue by adding this two lines to the Dockerfile.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV TZ=Europe/Kiev
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

ADD server.py .

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install python3
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN apt-get -y install python3-scapy
```